WRT1900ACS - OpenVPN server on stock firmware
I am trying to set up a VPN for my home network, which is managed by the Linksys WRT1900ACS, running on a stock firmware, set to autoupdate, currently on 1.0.3.187766.
When I enable the OpenVPN server and try to connect to it from a device with the OpenVPN client and a downloaded .ovpn file, I immediately get errors pertaining to the outdatedness of the security levels on the router. To week hashing... One can work around that by lowering the level of security expected by the client, but then you run into some next thing - can't remember which error now, but I'm already quite uncomfortable with the first workaround.
Is there a newer stock firmware that for some reason does not update automatically? Or is it just too old and lacks maintainance from Linksys/Cisco?
What are my options? Install a different more modern firmware on it? What are some examples of ones commonly accepted to be "good"?
Or do I need a newer router? Or do I want a VPN server on one of the machines inside the network? Please, advise!
PS. Ultimately I need remote access to a couple of things on the network: RDP, Home Assistant... Nothing fancy.
